# how do I serialize a boolean value?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to serialize the values from the array. The "Success" key is boolean.

I need to get this result: AUTHORIZEDtrue223344, but I can't. My result is: AUTHORIZED1223344. Please help me solve the problem.

```
$args = [
    "Status" => "AUTHORIZED",
    "UserId" => 223344,
    "Success" => true
];

$data = collect($args)->sortKeys()->filter(fn ($value, $key) => (string) $value)->join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert `boolean` to string then perform that action

like this

```php
$args = [
    "Status" => "AUTHORIZED",
    "UserId" => 223344,
    "Success" => true
];

$data = collect($args)->map(function ($item) {
    if (is_bool($item)) {
        return $item ? "true" : "false";
    }
    return $item;
})->values()->join("");
return $data;
```

it prints

> AUTHORIZED223344true

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use arrow function you can check:

```
$args = [
    "Status" => "AUTHORIZED",
    "UserId" => 223344,
    "Success" => true
];

$data = collect($args)
    ->sortKeys()
    ->map(fn($value, $key) => (string)(!is_bool($value) ? $value : ($value ? "true" : "false")))
    ->join('');
```

Comment: Thank you, brov! Have a good day/night! Thx again!

Comment: If it solved your problem you can upvote the answer and click checkmark from left top :)